# Is there a list of all ancient Hylian text in the game and its translation?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

Now that [the ancient Hylian font in Skyward Sword has been decoded](http://sarinilli.deviantart.com/art/Skyward-Sword-Ancient-Hylian-Font-277220924), is there a list or some other resource somewhere of all text in the game and its translation? I sometimes see text in the game but I don't see myself decoding it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should've searched harder. There appears to be a list [here](http://www.zeldauniverse.net/forums/skyward-sword-spoilers/136921-ss-hylian-alphabet.html).